# React FabricJS Grouping (JSX)

Tags: reactjs, canvas, fabricjs, jsx

NPM Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fabricjs

I'm using react-fabricjs and have a canvas with some icons showing. I'm now trying to get Grouping to work but I can't work out the syntax. Essentially I want to create this effect but using React JSX Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/anwjhs2o/1/

This is the code I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Canvas, Circle, Image, Path, Text, Rect, Ellipse, Triangle, Group} from 'react-fabricjs';


export default class CanvasFabric extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <Canvas
                ref="canvas"
                width="556"
                height="371"
            >
                <Circle
                    ref="circle"
                    radius={20}
                    left={100}
                    top={50}
                    stroke="green"
                    fill="blue"
                    blur={100}
                    color="rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"
                />
                <Image
                    src="https://cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/bountysource/image/twitter_name/d_noaoqqwxegvmulwus0un.png,c_pad,w_200,h_200,b_white/fabricjs.png"
                    width={64}
                    height={48}
                    left={10}
                    top={50}
                />
                <Rect
                    ref="rect1"
                    width={50}
                    height={50}
                    left={150}
                    top={150}
                    fill="orange"
                    shadow="rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 5px 5px 5px"
                />
                <Rect
                    ref="rect2"
                    width={60}
                    height={60}
                    left={145}
                    top={145}
                    stroke="purple"
                    strokeWidth={2}
                    blur={20}
                />
                <Ellipse
                    ref="ellipse"
                    width={20}
                    height={100}
                    offsetX={350}
                    offsetY={250}
                    stroke="orange"
                    strokeWidth={2}
                    fill="yellow"
                />
                <Triangle
                    ref="tri"
                    width={20}
                    height={20}
                    left={350}
                    top={250}
                    stroke="orange"
                    strokeWidth={1}
                    fill="black"
                    opacity={0.3}
                />
                <Text text="Edit me"
                    top={300}
                    left={10}
                    shadow="rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 5px 5px 5px"
                    stroke="#ff1318"
                    strokeWidth={1}
                    fontStyle="italic"
                    fontFamily="Hoefler Text"
                />
            </Canvas>
        )
    }



}
```

How could I say group the 2 Rect's - so they can be rotated/scaled etc together?

thankyou
Adam

** Extra Note: I'm no React Expert but I get the feeling the Fabric React Package is far from completed and this is why core functionality doesn't work.

Comment: is react-fabricjs a package? can you share a link?

Comment: sorry I didn't include it - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fabricjs

Comment: I spent some time checking that lib, i do not really get the use for it. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: Not sure if you should use this package just because you are using react. We are also using react with fabric js but we use the original fabric js. React application just maintain the state and based on the state changes you can still call the original fabrijs api because you actually don't need any new dom elements being rendered, you only need one canvas which you can render in the beginning of page load.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check the lib, i did not get how to use the group.

The main point is you should just use fabricJS in a normal way even if you are using reactJS. Binding a fabricjs render to a react render may be slow or just unnecessary.

The group code is using:
[image]

While the Group constructor in fabric is different.

You can try 2 approaches, the only 2 that makes sense in react:

```
      <Group>
        <Rect
            ref="rect1"
            width={50}
            height={50}
            left={150}
            top={150}
            fill="orange"
            shadow="rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 5px 5px 5px"
        />
        <Rect
            ref="rect2"
            width={60}
            height={60}
            left={145}
            top={145}
            stroke="purple"
            strokeWidth={2}
            blur={20}
        />
     </Group>
```

OR

```
      <Group
        objects={[<Rect
            ref="rect1"
            width={50}
            height={50}
            left={150}
            top={150}
            fill="orange"
            shadow="rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 5px 5px 5px"
        />,
        <Rect
            ref="rect2"
            width={60}
            height={60}
            left={145}
            top={145}
            stroke="purple"
            strokeWidth={2}
            blur={20}
        />]}
      />
```